# How to run Swift Timers in Asynchronous mode on particular Dispatch Queue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Here is the Sample code

```
import Combine
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Discover: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        demo().xyz()
        print("Hello1")
    }

    public class demo {
        func xyz() {
            discoveryHandlerQueue.async {
                var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

                print("Hello")
            }
        }

        @objc func timerAction() {
            print("timer fired!")
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to recieve timer callback here to print "timer fired!". Why is this happening.Moment I change it from async to sync everything runs smoothly

Comment: I believe this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231474/4081597

Comment: Using above runLoop , it Timer becomes blocking .So until we don't recieve call back for timeout ,"Hello" isn't printed

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dispatch_source_create` method to create timer, this timer can set running queue